# Pulling thumbnail image associated with a news article

Tags: android

I'm not sure if I'm tagging this question right, but I know a lot of news app like Pulse, Google Currents, etc. pull in a thumbnail of a news article.  My question is, I'm assuming they are pulling in the content from the news site itself, either screen scraping or consuming a feed of some kind.  How do they know which image to pull in from the site?

I'm tagging this with the "android" tag because I've built a news reader app that I'd like to pull in a thumbnail image.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I built such thing myself some time ago using this approach:

1. Process article with a Readability framework (for Java, Google found [jReadability](https://github.com/ifesdjeen/jReadability), [Snacktory](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/snacktory-yet-another-readability-clone-this-time-in-java/) and [Java-readability](https://github.com/basis-technology-corp/Java-readability) - there's probably more out there, one of which should run on Android, too).
2. In the processed article, grab the first image using some DOM framework to navigate to the first img tag. As the article is "clean", this is usually a usable hit.

I'd recommend to do the article processing on a server though, not on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](http://www.zemanta.com/blog/whats-the-best-thumbnail-for-this-page/), different techniques are discussed.

A good example of thumbnail extraction is preformed on [reddit](http://reddit.com).  Details on how reddit identifies and crops thumbnails are given [here](http://blog.reddit.com/2010/04/now-this-is-how-you-pitch-your-product.html) and [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/e9y6d/how_is_thumbbnail_formed/c16hwe0).